PDF link in React SPA works locally, but not in deployed production build
I am new to hosting a React app on a web server. What is the proper way to serve a PDF asset from a web server in a React app?
I've tried putting the PDF in the public folder, as well as  importing it into the component that has the anchor tag that uses it, but neither work after building for production (both methods work locally).
I put the contents of the dist folder from the build in the public_html folder on my website's hosting service, but it does not work. My hunch is that I may be getting something wrong with the file path/routing.
I am using Vite and Grommet component library. This is what the component that links to the pdf looks like:
import { 
    Anchor, 
    Avatar, 
    Box, 
    Header, 
    Heading, 
    Menu, 
    Nav, 
    ResponsiveContext 
} from 'grommet'
import resume from '../../docs/resume.pdf'

const CollapsibleNav = () => {
    return (
        <Header 
            background="dark-1" 
            pad="small"
            style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0px"
            }}
        >
            <Box 
                direction="row" 
                align="center" 
                gap="small"
            >
                <Avatar 
                    src={'headshot-circle.png'} 
                    size='medium'
                />
                <Heading 
                    size='small' 
                    margin='xsmall'
                >
                    My Name
                </Heading>
            </Box>
            <ResponsiveContext.Consumer>
            {(responsive) =>
                responsive === 'small' ? (
                <Menu
                    label="Menu"
                    items={[  
                    { label: 'Resume', onClick: () => {} },
                    ]}
                />
                ) : (
                <Nav direction="row">
                    <Anchor 
                    href={resume} 
                    label="Resume"
                    target="_blank" />
                </Nav>
                )
            }
            </ResponsiveContext.Consumer>
        </Header>
    )
}

export default CollapsibleNav;

When I click the link locally, the URL is http://localhost:5173/src/docs/resume.pdf. When I click it in production, the URL is http://mywebsite.com/assets/resume.pdf and instead of a new tab with the PDF displayed, a new tab opens with a page just like the homepage, but the image source in the Avatar component is broken.
As I said, this feels like a file path/routing, but I'm new to setting up web hosting, so I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong. Hopefully it's something simple I'm overlooking.
Thanks, ya'll!
